# Adding Row Specific context menu to an UltraWinGrid

Tags: row, contextmenu, ultrawingrid

I'm a newbie using `Infragistics`. I'm trying to add context menu to a specific row/column in `UltraWinGrid`, which I'm not able to. Looks like adding context menu to the grid is simple but adding it to a specific row/column is not straight forward. Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: You can read the following article http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/WinGrid_Using_the_WinGrid_ClickCell_Event_to_Show_a_Context_Menu.html

Answer (score 3):

You could add a context menu to the form or control your grid will reside in and only display it in when they right click in the grid over the rows/cells that need that menu.

Here's an example, though it's not pretty.

```
private void UltraGrid_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) 
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) 
  {
    ContextMenu.Hide();

    Point point = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
    UIElement uiElement = ((UltraGridBase) sender).DisplayLayout.UIElement.ElementFromPoint(point);
    UltraGridCell cell = (UltraGridCell) uiElement.GetContext(typeof (UltraGridCell));  

    if (cell != null && UseThisContextMenu(cell))
    {
      ContextMenu.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give a sample of what you are trying to say?

Comment: does that help? let me know if it needs some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

MouseDown does not work. Please use MouseUp.

```
private void UltraGrid1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {

            Point point = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
            UIElement uiElement = ((UltraGridBase)sender).DisplayLayout.UIElement.ElementFromPoint(point);
            UltraGridCell cell = (UltraGridCell)uiElement.GetContext(typeof(UltraGridCell));

            if (cell.Band.Index == 0)
            {
                if (cell.Column.Key.Equals("ColumnToShow"))
                {
                    contextMenuStrip.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    contextMenuStrip.Hide();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up